# How do I keep an ASP.NET TextBox from HTML-encoding its content?

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

the "problem" is that I do have an ASP.NET TextBox in a FormView with its Text property bound to a database table field. In some cases, there might be HTML-code combined with normal text in the database. The RequestEncoding and ResponseEncoding is set to "iso-8859-1" (whitch is latin1). There are some fields where latin1-characters and cyrillic characters may be combined. This is no problem when typing in cyrillic characters (e.g "д"). Because the RequestEncoding is set to iso-8859-1 and the charset for the browser as well, the browser will change д to "&#1076;", which will be saved in the database. That's what I want, but because "&#1076;" will be converted to "&amp;#1076;" when set to an ASP.NET TextBox's Text-property before the response output is sent to the browser, I do see "&#1076;" after saving the data.

Can anybody tell me how to stop ASP.NET from that conversion?

ALternatively: Is there a way to alter the conplete output of an ASPX site after all controls have ben rendered? - I could than replace "&amp;#" by "&#".

Comment: Where in the code is it a problem that the text is encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem (PortageMonkey showed me the way):

First I created a class "IsoTextBox" which inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox. Because the Text property does always returns a non-encoded string, simply changing the Text properties attribute did not do the job. Instead I overrote the Render method:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter source = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    base.Render(source);
    writer.Write(stringWriter.ToString().Replace("&amp;amp;#", "&#"));
}
```

And than added the tagMapping in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
      <pages>
        <tagMapping>
         <add mappedTagType="MyNamespace.IsoTextBox" tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"/>
        </tagMapping>
      </pages>
      <globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>
</system.web>
```

This works very well!

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished this simply inheriting from Textbox and overriding the Text property. It currently has the attribute PersistenceMode.EncodedInnerDefaultProperty.  You want to change it to InnerDefaultProperty:

```
[BindableAttribute(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
[PersistenceModeAttribute(PersistenceMode.EncodedInnerDefaultProperty)]
public virtual string Text { get; set; }
```

If you want this to apply to all your textboxes, you can use tag mappings to do it.

**Reference Material**

[More on Persistence Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.persistencemodeattribute.innerdefaultproperty(VS.71).aspx) 
[More on Textbox.Text property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx)
[More on Tag Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer pointed me the right way,please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can just decode the text before inserting it in the database:

```
string htmlEncodedText = myTextbox.Text;
string htmlDecodedText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(htmlEncodedText);

Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("8859-1");
Encoding utfEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utfEncoding .GetBytes(htmlDecodedText);
byte[] latinBytes =
    System.Text.Encoding.Convert(utfEncoding, latinEncoding, utfBytes);
string latinString = latinEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);

// TODO: Insert latinString into database
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the database must stay completely in latin1 characterset as well. No unicode or utf8 characters are allowed here