# Asp.Net encoding configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding

I am using ASP.NET 4 c# 2010.
Well my website has some problem with character encoding.
It seems that when I generate my output it is htmlencoded. So a ' is encoded with #number;... this is not always a good thing because when I need to dynamically insert jscript in my controls, every ' or " are encoded and js doesn't work properly...

How to correctly tell ASP.NET not to encode? or better telling him that he must correctly manage ' " and other chars like these withput rendering them htmlencoded?

An example of string being output: `this.MyControl.Attributes["onfocus"] = "execJs('param')"`

well it results so:

```
<textarea id=".." onfocus="execJs(&#39;param&#39;)">...
```

This is not correct.

Comment: I wonder if the difference is from the fact that you are using .NET 4? My version is 3.5.  (for newcomers, this is a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411419/asp-net-quote-character-encoding-causes-problems-when-setting-a-controls-propert/)

Comment: Well I can tell you that maybe YES it is because my previous sites in 3.5 do not suffer fomr this problem.. it's very disappointing when these things happen.. my god isn't therer any good damn reference  about this problem somewhere????????????

Comment: How are you outputting these strings? Can you post your code?

Comment: Here there is output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411419/asp-net-quote-character-encoding-causes-problems-when-setting-a-controls-propert

Answer (score 0):

OK got it, simply, there is nothing to worry about, here it is explained everything: [HTML Encoded strings recognized by the javascript engine, how's it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414108/html-encoded-strings-recognized-by-the-javascript-engine-hows-it-possible)